# How to pass a private type from another package in Ada

Tags: ada

Say I have a package like the following:

```
package binary_search_tree is
    type pointer is limited private;

    procedure insert (item : pointer);
private
    type node;
    type pointer is access node;
end binary_search_tree;
```

Now let's say I have a driver that wants to call foo like so:

```
with binary_search_tree;

procedure main is
    package new_tree is new binary_search_tree;
begin
    new_binary_search_tree.insert(???);
end
```

So what I'm trying to do is create a binary search tree package and implement it in a driver. The specifications require me to declare a node pointer type as limited private inside the binary tree package, and it expects me to pass the pointer to the root of a binary tree into its functions through the driver. However, I'm not sure how I can do that if the pointer type is private. Unless I'm missing something, I wouldn't think I'm supposed to do that to begin with. Doesn't that violate encapsulation?

Comment: It looks as though `Binary_Search_Tree` is meant to be generic. What is it generic _in_? `Integer`, for example? You can’t want to `Insert` a `Pointer`, surely? And, in `Main`, what is `foo` in `new_binary_search_tree.foo(???);`? Do you mean `Item`?

Comment: Yes, foo is supposed to be insert. My apologies. 

Yes, the package is supposed to be generic. It has two generic parameters in my actual implementation: key, and tree_record. When I implement it in the main procedure, I'm supposed to pass a string in for the key (a name) and tree_record is to become a record with a name and phone number, both of which are strings. 

Also, no, I don't intend to insert a pointer. The pointer to be passed as a parameter is supposed to point to the root of the tree I wish to insert a new node into.

Answer (score 3):

Your `pointer` type is in the visible part of `binary_search_tree`, so any instantiation has a type `pointer` too. It’s `limited private`, so you can declare variables of that type; you can pass them to subprograms (such as `insert`), you just can’t compare one to another, copy them, or use any knowledge of the contents.

Your generic (absent any actual detail, but compilable) would look like

```
generic
   type Element is private;
package Binary_Search_Tree is
   type Tree is limited private;

   procedure Insert (Into : in out Tree; Item : Element);
private
   type Node;
   type Tree is access Node;
   type Node is record
      --  pointer stuff
      Value : Element;
   end record;
end Binary_Search_Tree;
```

The user program (is that what you mean by “driver”?) would look like

```
with Binary_Search_Tree;

procedure Main is
   package New_Tree is new Binary_Search_Tree (Integer);
   T : New_Tree.Tree;
begin
   New_Tree.Insert (T, 123);
end Main;
```